# Does Core Data provide an existential query for NSFetchRequest?

Tags: core-data

Given an `NSManagedObjectContext` and an `NSFetchRequest`, I'd like to know if a non empty result set will be returned should I issue the fetch request.

A method `countForFetchRequest:error:` exists, which could be used. It certainly seems better than actually performing the request and getting the objects (or faults) back. However, in many cases, it's enough to know that there are *some*: the exact number doesn't matter at all.

Comment: I think `countForFetchRequest:error:` is the best bet.  If it's any consolation, it seems (at least for some reasonably complex fetches that I have just tested) to use SQL to do the count, rather than performing the fetch and counting the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you don't care what the exact number is, the question you're asking is still "is the count greater than zero"? There's no specific built-in method for that, so asking for the count and comparing the result to zero is the right way to do it. It's also less expensive in terms of memory and time, since you don't spend time fetching objects you don't need into memory.

You **could** do something like execute the fetch with a `fetchLimit` of 1, but that's more obscure (you're fetching stuff you don't need).

Comment: I noticed in the documentation for `countForFetchRequest:error:` that it vaguely hints that if you set the `fetchLimit`, you might only get 1 result when there are more? I probably need to try that out.

Comment: I don't know. I might have misspoken, my intention was to recommend against using fetchLimit in this case.

Comment: **nods** I agree with you that actually fetching just one _probably_ isn't a great idea, unless it really helps and testing shows its faster. If the count interface works with a limit of one, though (and is actually quicker), that'd be pretty cool.